# Is Python's nested "if-else" different from "if" with "and" condition?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have recently been ripping my hair out trying to track down a bug, and I've come to realize that my understanding of how Python evaluates statements is lacking in some respects.

Does Python make any relevant differences in how it handles nested if statements vs. if... and blocks?

For example:

```
if profile_username == input_username and profile_password == input_password:
    log_in(loaded_profile)
```

How does this differ from

```
if profile_username == input_username:
    if profile_password == input_password:
        log_in(loaded_profile)
```

They both evaluate lazily, and they both require both conditions to be met, but otherwise, I don't know if they're identical.

Will one version create some behavior (BUGS???) that the other won't? In a situation like this, is it simply programmer preference which one to use?

Comment: You should talk about the bug so that the answers might be more relevant?

Comment: The bug is involving a system log-in: clients are not able to log into a system, and I'm attempting to identify where the log in reasoning might go wrong. In general, I've been told SO is not the place to be posting specific bug instances asking for debug help, so I have refrained from doing so here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` logic will remain the same in both the cases, but your `else` logic will differ. For example:

```
if condition_1 and condition_2:
    # something
else:
    # something else
```

Here `else` will be executed if any of the `condition_1` or `condition_2` fails.

But if your conditional statements are like:

```
if condition_1:
    if condition_2:
        # something
    else:
        # something else
else:
    # something else
```

Here you need to define your else block for both `condition_1` and `condition_2`. If any `else` block is missing, you'll get different result.

Comment: Thanks! Since the only `else` blocks I'm using in the code in question is attached to a `try:` statement, I know that I do not have to be concerned with the behavior of my if statements.